# Tools to get objective c's methods when application is running

Tags: objective-c, macos, reverse-engineering

For example if we have textedit application, now when we click 'Save' option. I want to know which objective c methods that are being called at the application at runtime.
For this which tools i can use.

Comment: will you please be specific

Comment: @NarendraPandey   For ex.. Let's say after using class-dump you get all header files and you know the classes and methods of particular application(ex TextEdit).  Now I want to know when I press save button on textedit ...which methods get called ?

Comment: is there any way by using dtrace